# $\dot y=y^2-t$ Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

Liouville proved that the differential equation $\dot y=y^2-t$ does not have a solution in form of algebraic equations. Do you know any reference where I can find the proof for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Theorem 6.6. in [Introduction to Differential Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/2705612513).

Comment: Thanks for the reference, if you have also a link to some work from liouville itself it would be very interesting. Beside, may you can help me transforming the differential equation to an autonomous system, then I sketch the portrait in the (t,y) plane, but I do not know how to tranform it.

Comment: Here is the [paper](http://portail.mathdoc.fr/JMPA/PDF/JMPA_1841_1_6_A1_0.pdf) by Liouville. To transform this equation into autonomous system you need just add equation $\dot t=1$